# Multiple STA (Single Thread Apartment ) is not working in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a simple asp.net web application. It has two buttons one for browsing folder  (selectFolderbtn) & another for browsing file (selectFilebtn) . And the click event for both the buttons are as below:-

```
protected void selectFolderbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Thread thdSyncRead = new Thread(new ThreadStart(openfolder));
     thdSyncRead.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     thdSyncRead.Start();
 }

 public void openfolder()
 {

     FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
     DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

     string selectedfolder = fbd.SelectedPath;
     txt_extDestLoc.Text = selectedfolder;


 }


protected void selectFilebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Thread thdSyncReadNew = new Thread(new ThreadStart(selectfile));
     thdSyncReadNew.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     thdSyncReadNew.Start();



 }

public void selectfile()
 {

     OpenFileDialog fileD = new OpenFileDialog(); //create object
     fileD.Filter = "Iso files|*.iso;"; //define filter
     fileD.ShowDialog(); //show dialog
     string globalisopath = fileD.FileName;

 }
```

The issue I am facing is, among the above two button click event only one event works at a time & not both the event. I want both the click event to work, one should select a folder & another should select a file. But its not working the way I want.

Why this is happening. Please suggest me its solution or any other alternatives.

Comment: `OpenFileDialog` in a web app???

Comment: `"only one event works at a time"` that's how it is, but `OpenFileDialog`!!!???

Comment: In place of OpenFileDialog (windows control) I could have used FileUpload web control. But the problem with FileUpload control is that it does not give us the full path of the browsed file it only returns file name in Firefox. The same FileUpload control returns the full file path in IE but not in Firefox. So I tried to use OpenFileDialog for this purpose. string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName) returns the full path in IE. But its not working in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You're solving the wrong issue.

There is no legitimate reason to use any windows dialog in a web application. It will only ever show the dialog on the *server* (and most likely, not even that). You need to handle this on your own - either you want the user to upload some files, and there's controls for that, or you want him to select a file / folder already existing on the *server* - and that's completely different.

You cannot use any windows controls in a web application at all. You need to use web controls, or write your own HTML+JavaScript etc.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me not to use windows control in web application.I tried to use Windows control in a web application only because FileUpload contorl does not return the full path of the file browsed in Firefox due to security reason.But the same FileUpload controls gives us the full path in IE.

Comment: @VishwajeetMCA Yes, development isn't exactly easy. But you're missing the point - you don't care about the path of the file in the FileUpload - you take the data the client has sent you, you don't connect to the client and ask him for a file at a given path. You don't see most of the issues with your thinking because you have the client on the same machine as the server, and both are probably running as admins in a UI session. Try setting the server up on a different machine and you'll see the issues a lot better :)